# i need an advice about winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

basically, i made an application on the console that sends and receives information. it works like a chat (it does work, like i chat, i checked).

now what i did here. i transfered some of the code to a winform, and i struggle to understand how can i make the output received (readLine) be printed on the label and input to be sent by the textfield!!

could you direct me and tell me where my mistakes, and how can i make the chat work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpClient connection;
        StreamReader sr;
        StreamWriter sw;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void connectServer()
        {
             connection = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5000);
             sr = new StreamReader(connection.GetStream());
             sw = new StreamWriter(connection.GetStream());
        }

        void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                sw.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
                sw.Flush();            
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = sr.ReadLine();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: At the minute you have it populating the label when the user clicks the label.  What / when exactly do you want the data returned to the label?

Comment: Lots of things are missing from the code you've posted. For example, you never call the `connectServer` method. Is that the problem, or did you just not post all of your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So...

you can chat from where to where? **same machine**, **same network**, **internet**?

You need to create a **service to handle the conversation**, a **global point** for all chats, that gets the message and saves it.

Then you need to, from each client, hook up to that global point and create a "room" and **attach the client as an observable**, every time there is a new message in that "room", all observable clients will be warn of incoming message and update their textbox.

If you want to **avoid a "global point" you can use sockets**, though, it might not work if the client is somewhere behind a NAT.

here is a full application in **WCF**

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWPFChat.aspx

Comment: You can do a peer-to-peer chat. The server is useful but not essential.

Comment: I did told that after "if you want to avoid" ... no idea why the downvote, I never say you can't... I explain both ways.